# Find whether double length or triple length 3DES is used

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, 3des, tripledes

I am reviewing an application and we are supposed to check the Encryption algorithm and the strength of the keys used. From my review of the code, what i could figure out is they are using 3DES algorithm, which i figured out from the line which mentioned "**DES/ECB/NoPadding**" in use.

However after googling about the encryption, i figured out that the encryption mentioned above is only having a key size of 56 bits. The reference link is given below:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html

However, the application developers are saying that they use Double length 3DES. With the above data we only can figure out that 3DES has been used, cannot figure out the keysize. The application is developed in JAVA.

Can someone help me what could be the way to find out that double length or triple length 3DES has been used?

(OR)

Provide double length or triple length 3DES implementation details? so that we can figure out the what could be used in my situation.

Comment: How do you expect to review encryption code without a substantial background of knowledge with respect to encryption?

Comment: It's probably outdated documentation or they simply don't know what they are talking about. Either way, DES and two-key 3DES should not be used nowadays, because they provide only 56 and 80 bit of security. I suggest to use AES which has better security guarantee with the smallest key size than any DES/3DES variant.

Answer (score 1):

If they're using javax.crypto with only `DES/ECB/NoPadding`, then they're not using `3DES`, they're using `DES`. Not only that, they're using `ECB` which is definitely not recommended. Of course they could have rolled their own "double length 3DES" (whatever that means) with the standard DES, but that's another warning sign.

P.S. If you had to google about encryption, why are you even reviewing the code? You have no idea whether the code is secure or not, as evidenced by this question.

Comment: Note the OP clams to be a "Security Analyst".

Comment: Freelance security analyst, ouch.

Comment: I'm not someone with a coding background, neither am an analyst at coding, security analysts cater to other aspects of security as well. Thought of taking help from experts but seems some are here only to boast themselves. I dont want you to review it for me, just pointing the right approach was more than enough. THanks a lot.

Comment: @mjoi Then I hope you've told your clients that you're reviewing cryptographic code that you have no idea about. It seems like you're one of the security risks involved in the project now.

Comment: yes aboslutely, i have told them and they know that i am reviewing cryptographic code that I have no idea about and, they also have so called developers probably like you who doesnt know what they have made.

Comment: So, we have developers "probably doesnt know what they have made" and a security reviewer who is "not someone with a coding background" reviewing encryption the code. I do not see how this can have a good outcome. Consider that it is the users who are at risk from poor security (encryption in this case), they expect and deserve proper security.

Comment: My friend, as i have mentioned earlier, i am not a code reviewer, I am trying to understand the application for someone. It's definitly not for giving coding recommendations or improve security, but to first find what it is. Any help is appreciated, if not interested in helping, dont bother. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

First of, I'm no expert in cryptography so take this answer with some moderation.

What is double length 3DES?

> Triple DES encipherment involves enciphering an 8-byte plaintext block in an
>   8-byte ciphertext block with a double-length (16-byte) secret key K = (K<sub>L</sub> || K<sub>R</sub>) as follows:
>   Y = DES3(K)[X] = DES(K<sub>L</sub>)[ DES<sup>-1</sup> (K<sub>R</sub>)[DES(K<sub>L</sub>)[X] ] ] 
>   Decipherment takes place as follows:
>   X = DES<sup>-1</sup> (K<sub>L</sub> )[ DES(K<sub>R</sub> )[ DES<sup>-1</sup> (K<sub>L</sub>)[Y] ] ]

*Taken from  [EMV 4.2: Book 2 - Security and Key Management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES#cite_note-22).*

---

Here is how one would implement this in Java:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Test3DES {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {
        //byte length has to be mutiple of 8!
        String plaintext = "Attack at dawn!!";
        byte[] plainBytes = plaintext.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] encrypted = encrypt(plainBytes);
        byte[] decrypted = decrypt(encrypted);

        System.out.println("Original message: ");
        System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", plaintext);
        System.out.printf("Raw bytes: %s%n", toHexString(plainBytes));
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Encrypted message: ");
        System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", new String(encrypted, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.printf("Raw bytes: %s%n", toHexString(encrypted));
        System.out.println("---");
        System.out.println("Decrypted message: ");
        System.out.printf("Text: %s%n", new String(decrypted, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.printf("Raw bytes: %s%n", toHexString(decrypted));
    }

    private static String toHexString(byte[] array) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : array) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X ", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        Cipher encr1, decr2, encr3;
        SecretKeySpec kL, kR, tmp;

        kL = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, "DES");
        kR = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[] {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15}, "DES");

        encr1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        decr2 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        encr3 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");

        encr1.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kL);
        decr2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kR);
        encr3.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kL);

        return encr3.doFinal( decr2.doFinal( encr1.doFinal(message) ) );
    }

    private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] message) throws Exception {
        Cipher decr1, encr2, decr3;
        SecretKeySpec kL, kR;

        kL = new SecretKeySpec(
            new byte[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
            "DES"
        );
        kR = new SecretKeySpec(
            new byte[] {8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
            "DES"
        );

        decr1 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        encr2 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");
        decr3 = Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/NoPadding");

        decr1.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kL);
        encr2.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, kR);
        decr3.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, kL);

        return decr3.doFinal( encr2.doFinal( decr1.doFinal(message) ) );
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Original message: 
Text: Attack at dawn!!
Raw bytes: 41 74 74 61 63 6B 20 61 74 20 64 61 77 6E 21 21 
---
Encrypted message: 
Text: #�Jɚe�P�ϸ5�%t�
Raw bytes: 23 B4 4A C9 9A 65 C5 50 90 CF B8 35 9A 25 74 A2 
---
Decrypted message: 
Text: Attack at dawn!!
Raw bytes: 41 74 74 61 63 6B 20 61 74 20 64 61 77 6E 21 21
```

---

So to answer your question - you're looking for 16 bytes key size in the code. In my snippet the key is composed of `kL` and `kR`, which are 8 bytes each, totalling 16.

Comment: Since encrypted data is essentially random bytes and not printable characters it is usual to present it as hexadecimal, `#�Jɚe�P�ϸ5�%t�` is meaningless and not even the correct length. It would also be bizarre to use three DES instances for encryption vs using 3DES, many 3DES implementations that if presented with a 16-byte key will by default use the first 8-bytes for the 3rd 8-bytes. Interestingly the keys are a bad example because DES ignores the lsb of each byte, that bit was initially used for parity, thus `{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7}` and `{0,0,2,2,4,4,6,6}` are essentially the same key.

Comment: @zaph I realize now that printable character representation is a poor choice - you are very welcome to edit my answer if I don't do so before you. So you're saying I should instead use 3DES with key `{kL, kR, kL}`? It does seem like a better idea! And about the keys I don't think the strength is important in this context but still... thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @zaph And it was stated in the question that Ciphers were instantiated with **DES/ECB/NoPadding** algorithm. If this question is to be helpful I still think it should retain this form and perhaps just mention improvements.

Comment: Yes, DES vs 3DES, the question is confusing.